# Removing spaces from specific columns of pipe seperated file

Tags: powershell, csv, import-csv

I'm trying to remove spaces from columns 15 and 16 in a pipe seperated file.

I've tried the code at the bottom of this post after searching the web but it's failing with

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At line:19
>   char:2
>   +     $*.h15=$*.h15.ToString().Replace(' ','')
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

and

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At line:20
>   char:5
>   +     $*.h16=$*.h16.ToString().Replace(' ','')
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNul

I guess from that, that it's not reading in the data but I can't see why not. I've checked the variables and they are correct.

```
$header = 1..42 | ForEach-Object { "h$_" }
$dialler_out_path="$dialler_file_dir\$output_file"

$dialler_path="$dialler_file_dir\$dialler_file"

(Import-Csv -Delimiter '|' -Header $header -Path $dialler_path | %{ 
    $_.h15=$_.h15.ToString().Replace(' ','')
    $_.h16=$_.h16.ToString().Replace(' ','')
}) | export-csv $dialler_out_path -NoType
```

Comment: The problem appear to be that you are trying to do a ToString on a null object, try instead to do Convert.ToString which handles nulls

Comment: Try: `(Import-Csv -Delimiter '|' -Header $header -Path $dialler_path | ? {$_} | %`{...

Comment: This still gives the null value exception. I've just added an extra pipe and the code ? {$_} as above but still it errors. Unfortuantely I can't post any sample data to help because it's sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Another way to deal with null object (in addition to comments):

`$_.h15 = (-join ($_.h15)).ToString().Replace(' ','')`

You should produce output in foreach:

```
(Import-Csv -Delimiter '|' -Header $header -Path $dialler_path | %{ 
$_.h15 = (-join ($_.h15)).ToString().Replace(' ','')
$_.h16 = (-join ($_.h16)).ToString().Replace(' ','')

$_

}) | export-csv $dialler_out_path -NoType
```

Comment: This didn't throw any errors but the output file was empty.